# My emulator is not open with this "Android Emulator closed because of an internal error."

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

When I execute emulator, I got this error.

[image]

I tried:

```
1. wipe data of emulator and delete device from emulator list.
2. Reinstall Android studio
3. Download all SDK needed.
```

But none of them helped me. My android version is 3.6.3

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try update graphics driver, This is [the official site](https://www.amd.com/en/support)